# N2 Customize Login Logic

Tags: c#, n2, n2cms

We have a need to customize the logic of our N2 authentication to add a couple of options.

I need to add a RadioButtonList that contains some options and set a session var based on the selection of that RadioButton on Login - otherwise the user cannot see the site in the preview pane of N2. I thought I could just add the RadioButtonList to the N2/Login.aspx and create a custom Login Class that extended N2.Edit.Login and override the Login1_Authenticate method to do my custom logic before calling base.Login1_Authenticate. It seems that it is not designed to be extensible and I cannot override that method. To make my change I would have to do a custom compile of N2 with these changes, which I want to avoid (should be closed to modification but open to extension) so we don't have to redo our changes every time we update N2.

Another route I tried was to create N2/CustomLogin.aspx and add all of my logic in that custom class and set the web.config to point to CustomLogin.aspx instead of Login.aspx - this sent me to the correct login page initially but a failed login redirected me to Login.aspx (assuming something hard coded) which did not have our radio button options.

We are using N2 CMS 2.0.0.0 on .Net 4.0 (MVC app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

N2 uses standard Forms Auth, ASP.NET Membership and Roles providers under the covers. As long as the logged on user is either named admin or is in one of the 3 N2 standard roles (Administrators, Editor and Authors - I think), you will be able to access the admin site.

So I recommend you create a completely separate login page in your app. Point forms auth at your custom login page using an entry like this in your web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/account/login"
         timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

In your custom login form you can do the standard forms auth stuff to get the user signed in, as well as setting your session variable.

I've done this a few times and it works fine. If you can't get it working I suggest you provide a sample that demonstrates the problem and I'll see if I can help.